# Xamarin.Forms: How can I load ResourceDictionary from another file?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wrote following code, but XamlParseException has bean thrown. ("StaticResource not found for key CustomColor")

MyPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XFApp11.MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomResource.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <BoxView Color="{StaticResource CustomColor}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

CustomResource.xaml (build action = EmbeddedResource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="CustomColor">#004B86</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Merged Dictionaries aren't supported in Xamarin Forms XAML below 2.1.0

The only way you can do it, is to put it in another page and then load it up in code behind and reference it via DynamicResource instead of StaticResource.

I explain this more here: http://www.xamarinhelp.com/styling-uiux-day-11/

However as of 2.1.0-pre1 (released this week), you can now do templating, which is another way to do this. Jason Smith has blogged about it: http://xfcomplete.net/general/2016/01/20/control-templates/

**Update:** As of 2.3.0 you can do a Merged Dictionary with an attribute called MergedWith.

Create a new XAML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="UIDemo.Style.NewStyle">
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now in your ContentPage use the MergedWith attribute on your ResourceDictionary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:UIDemo.Style"
             x:Class="UIDemo.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="theme:NewStyle" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Text="Hello" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, ResourceDictionary.Source property is also not supported?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I vaguely remember looking into it a while back. You can't reference another XAML file for your resource dictionary in XF. But I haven't gone and tested that just now, so if you can, someone please correct me :)

Comment: I followed your answers, when I'm debugging I see Resources list, the Count property is including all my resource (my code is 54) but the Keys and Values is not (my code is only 1 key and value). It also runtime error for cannot found resource key XXX. Look like it knows merged resource but it's not applied

Comment: My Xamarin Forms version is 2.3.2.127

Comment: @AdamPedley can I create multiple resource dictionary files and merge them in App.xaml?

Comment: @batmaci - not that I know of, it is one of the limitations that there is only one MergedWith property and it only accepts one style.

Comment: @batmaci - though its something I have always wanted as well, so I submitted an API request to Xamarin for it. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86308/multiple-merged-dictionaries

Answer (score 15):

As of 2.3.0 can officially merge Resource dictionaries in xaml
observe the following example

**BlueTheme.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="UI.Themes.BlueTheme">
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:UI.Themes"
             x:Class="UI.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="themes:BlueTheme" />
    </Application.Resources>
    <Label Text="Hello" />
</Application>
```

Comment: What type you used to inherit BlueTheme.xaml.
Could you share code BlueTheme.xaml.cs

Comment: This should be clear from the Xaml: ***ResourceDictionary*** if it had a different base class i´d need to write something similar to ***local:ResourceDictionary***

Comment: This should be clear from the Xaml: ***ResourceDictionary*** if it had a different a custom base class i´d need to write something similar to ***custom-namespace:ResourceDictionary***

Also ***ResourceDictionary*** is `public` as of ***2.3.0***

Comment: I do exactly the same, it updates the count of Resoures but it doesn't update the Keys and Values. That make runtime error.

Comment: @AhmedAlejo, I need to define my resources in non embedded file. Is there way to merge resource dictionary from asset files? I mean loading resource dictionary at run time.

Comment: @Manikandan **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.LoadFromXaml<TXaml>(this TXaml view, string xaml)** is public as of **Xamarin.Forms.2.3.2.127**

Comment: don't forget to call InitializeComponent() in the constructor of your UI.Themes.BlueTheme class. found working sample here - https://xamarinhelp.com/merged-dictionaries-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 4):

From **Xamarin.Forms 3.0** `MergedWith` has been deprecated and should not be used.

Now you can use either `Source` or `MergeDictionaries`.

**MyResource.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="UI.MyResource">
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So, if `MyResource.xaml` is in the same assembly you can use directly:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="UI.AnotherResource"
    Source="MyResource.xaml">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Otherwise (`MyResource.xaml` is on another assembly):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:otherresources="clr-namespace:OtherAssembly.UI.Resources"
    x:Class="UI.AnotherResource">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <otherresources:MyResource />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Some things to take into consideration:

- Source: It can only be used in XAML, and the value is the path to the xaml file (always in same assembly)
- MergeDictionaries: It can be used regardless of the assembly where the resource reside

More info in [Xamarin Forms Resource Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merged-resource-dictionaries)

Comment: everybody is writing different way and xamarin is keep changing such basic thing. your sample is also outdated now

Comment: why do you think it's updated? the official docs still says to use `Source` and `MergeDictionaries`. What new thing are you referring to @batmaci? And btw, if you are going to make a comment like that, please provide useful information instead of just criticise the technology

Comment: it is just big confusing the documentation of xamarin. I thought first Source property is enhancement and better version of merged dictionaries. they wrote as if that you should use source within the same assembly and mergeddictionaries when another assembly. Obviously both can be used and i believe that they have different way of execution. One is creating instance and another doesnt everytime page resources are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes after hours fighting with this:

- `MergedWith` is deprecated. Use `Source` instead.
- Despite what [the official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/design-consistent-xaml-pages-with-shared-resources-and-styles/8-create-and-use-applicationwide-resources) says, it doesn't seem to be possible to load a resource dictionary defined within a separate `ContentPage`. The resource dictionary needs to be its own `.xaml` file.
- Despite what another answer says, the value of `Source` is just the name of the .xaml file, *not* the path to  it.
- From [this comment](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/209672/#Comment_209672), the .xaml file containing your shared resources MUST:

  - ..have a root-element of type `ResourceDictionary`
  - ..have a .xaml.cs backing file (deleting it causes it to silently fail)
  - ..inherit from `ResourceDictionary` in the backing file
  - ..be in the same assembly as the .xaml using it *(it's apparently possible to share styles across assemblies using `MergedDictionaries`, but I wasn't able to get this to work)*

Answer (score 1):

After also struggleing with this Topic I came to a solution using the `MergedDiciontaries`

```xml
<Application ... xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:AppName.Resources;assembly=AppName" xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Company.Design;assembly=Company.Design">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <theme:Theme/> <!--ResourceDictionary from another assembly -->
                <resources:StylesAndTemplates/> <!--ResourceDictionary from the same assembly also StylesAndTemplates which uses colors / style from "Theme" ResourceDictionary -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ...
        </ResourceDictionary>
        ...
    </Application.Resources>
    ...
</Application>
```